# Why aren't canvas lines visible?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I am building up to a rotating hypercube on an HTML5 Canvas, but before that goal I am reaching a basic difficulty with the Canvas. I have a white/uncolored canvas, and I am trying to draw lines after setting fillStyle and strokeStyle to '#000000', and I have not yet succeeded at getting any pixel on the canvas to appear other than white.

The canvas is at http://blajeny.com/tesseract.html , and the JavaScript which is part math and part old-fashioned JavaScript, is at http://blajeny.com/js/tesseract.js . The log says that it is drawing lines on the canvas, some of which should intersect the 500x500 canvas and some of which should lie completely inside the canvas, but all I can see is pure white.

The math side of it needs work in terms of projection from a higher- to a lower-dimensional surface. However the difficulty I am trying to address now is a basic HTML5 canvas issue in that I am setting a color, moving to and drawing a line to coordinates some of which overlap and some of which are within the 500x500 canvas, and not seeing anything turn black. (The JavaScript console logs the lines I am trying to draw.)

How can I get the lines I am trying to draw to show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let canvas know when you start and stop drawing using context.beginPath() and context.stroke()/context.fill().  Here's code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Jw8XU/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(50, 75);
      ctx.lineTo(150, 150);
      ctx.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```